# Prevent users from generating authentication tokens

Tags: php, ios, api, security

So I have an API with an endpoint like so `POST http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate`.
Go to that and you POST an `email` and `password` and you get an authentication token. Seems solid so far.

Now what about registering. I'd need to create some sort of request token, but how would I prevent random users from creating a request token through the API? I was thinking of generating the token from `http://localhost:8080/api/request` then returning it and checking if it existed when a user went to register. The thing is anybody can go to `http://localhost:8080/api/request`, even if they're not planning on registering. Any idea?

Comment: Are you checking if the email/password in the database returns true before issuing the auth-token?

Comment: That's correct. I just can't figure out a safe way to generate tokens for unregistered users. Since this is an iOS project I'm trying to prevent users from generating the auth-token from the web @JordanDavis

Comment: It won't matter what device is connecting just extract the variables from the $POST and then check against the database if the user does exist then create the session. I'll post an example below.

Comment: What do you think the problem is with "anyone can get a request token"?

Comment: Well then anybody could access the API and post through the web, when it's an iOS app. I know it's not entirely possible to prevent is, since after all, it is an API. But I'm just trying to figure out the best way to stop it @adelphus

Comment: @adelphus I believe he is generate the token when they visit the page instead of doing it after the user-authentication process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authenticate the user before you generate an auth-token(cookie)... so write a query to pull the id from the user table where email/password matches... so only if the query returns an id then you know the user exists and is  "authenticated", therefore you can now generate a auth-token(cookie) setting it to the usrid...

However setting the cookie to the usrid is not a good practice! since anyone on the client-side could easily set/pass a cookie with a number in a POST request... you need implement some mechanism of encryption to generate a "session" which you can then use as a unique hack-proof user identifier.

I wrote a simple encryption function in the code below which you can use.

```
<?php
//CHECK IF POST DATA IS EMPTY IF SO KILL THE SCRIPT
if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
    //echo("error msg"); 
    die();
}
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'accounts');
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '" 
    . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']) 
    . "' AND `password` = '" 
    . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']) . "'"; 

//INITIATE DB REQUEST
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
//SELECT ID(OBJ) FROM THE RESULT OBJECT
$usrid = $result->fetch_object()->id;
//IF $USRID IS TRUE... USER DOES EXIST (AUTHENTICATED) 
if ($usrid) {
    $sesh = create_session($usrid);
    update_session($usrid, $sesh);
    setcookie("usersesh", $sesh, 0,"/");
} else {
    //echo("error msg");
}

$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
function create_session($usrid) {
    $time = microtime();
    $hash = substr($time, 2, 3);
    $key = $usrid * $hash;
    $sesh = md5($key);
    return $sesh;   
}
function update_session($usrid, $sesh) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'accounts');
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `session` = '" 
        . $mysqli->real_escape_string($sesh) . "' WHERE `id` = '" 
        . $mysqli->real_escape_string($usrid) . "'"; 
    $mysqli->query($query);
    $mysqli->close();   
}
?>
```

Comment: Escape the `$email` parameter to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Yea was just adding the note at the top when you posted that.

Comment: Also note it's not good practice to set userid as a cookie since anyone could generate a usrid client side, and hack there way in to anyones account... so what you really want to do is create another field in your db called "session", once you've check that the user does exist and return the id like the example above... you should then pass that id to a simple function that encrypts the id via (microtime/md5) and then update the session field for the user and then set the encrypted session as the token instead of the number id. If you have time I'll update the code and show you if you want?

Comment: I already got that part down, but should I create a request token for every request, then to authenticate I should require that request token? I feel like that's part of it. Unless it's the other way around (auth-token->request)?  That's the key part I'm stuck at.

Comment: @sven read the comments I already stated that, and like he said he has already has that...

Comment: @Idris yea so don't issue an auth token (cookie) until you verified that there email/password exists... so basically in the example above your pulling the id from the db where the email/password exist, then if there is an id where the email/pass match, create the auth token (cookie).

Comment: So generate request tokens for everything, then authentication tokens, for authentication. Correct? @JordanDavis

Comment: @Idris No generate the request token until you verify that there email/password matches and that in fact they are a registered user... When the user signins in from what ever device they're still posting a email/password (credentials) verify the credentials first and if they match then generate a token for them (cookie) if they don't match then it simply won't generate a token for them.

Comment: @Idris I just update the code above with encryption and comments let me know if you confused on anything.

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks for bearing with me! I suggest you update the answer with some of the comments about the tokens and so fourth!

Comment: `strip_tags()` is NO SQL ESCAPING function! `md5()` is no secure password hashing function. `extract()` pollutes the global variable scope with arbitrary, attacker-defined values and increases the risk in case of using uninitialized variables. The "encryption" function to create a token is dangerously low on using randomness - and it has a serious bug that will create the same token for everyone. The comments confuse `md5()` with encryption. All in all I must say that this code looks outright dangerous even on the lowest level, because there are so many basic things wrong!

Comment: @Sven we already discussed this he already did that what don't understand do you want me to add it or something? don't have a heart-attack. The md5() hash is standard lol... even so I'm multiplying mirco-time and usrid to add a 2nd level of encryption before I even md5() hash it, want to get more encrypted... you could to microtime by the user_password... and if it's so "dangerously low" why don't you try hacking it, and while your at it go read up on the md5 hash algorithm.

Comment: @Sven not trying to hate on you but we already discussed sql escaping... I don't think you understand encryption... and don't think you know what he is trying to do in terms of making in authentication API.

Comment: @JordanDavis Hashing is not encryption, it is a one-way function. If you want a unique random session ID get random bytes or a GUID, home-grown methods tend to be weak, use well vetted methods. MD5 should not be used in new work, just use SHA256 or above, it is just as easy to use and secure. If you want to create a key from a password use PBKDF2 (Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2) with a substantial repetition count, that is the current best practice. Finally attacking Sven is just wrong and his comment is well founded. –  zaph 55 mins ago

Comment: @JordanDavis It's funny that you are telling me that I might not be understanding encryption, but fail to correct your own simple code even after I put a BIG NOTICE in it: `$key = $id * $hash; // MULTIPLYING WITH AN UNINITIALIZED VARIABLE RESULTS IN 0` Removing that comment doesn't fix the problem.